# How to quickly iterate over rows in a very large dataframe to apply str_split and extract second last element to replace value in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, vectorization, stringr

I have a very large dataframe (750,000+ rows) and I need to change the data in there from:

```
                    V        W      X       Y                                                          Z
1   1085_S4_kaiju.out 0.697392 418154   28901                                          Bacteria;Pseudomonadota;Gammaproteobacteria;Enterobacterales;Enterobacteriaceae;Salmonella;Salmonella enterica;

2   1085_S4_kaiju.out 0.692621 415293     562                                           Bacteria;Pseudomonadota;Gammaproteobacteria;Enterobacterales;Enterobacteriaceae;Escherichia;Escherichia coli;

3   1085_S4_kaiju.out 0.690187 413834     470                                    Bacteria;Pseudomonadota;Gammaproteobacteria;Moraxellales;Moraxellaceae;Acinetobacter;Acinetobacter baumannii;

4   1085_S4_kaiju.out 0.625289 374921     573                                      Bacteria;Pseudomonadota;Gammaproteobacteria;Enterobacterales;Enterobacteriaceae;Klebsiella;Klebsiella pneumoniae;

5   1085_S4_kaiju.out 0.285564 171223   33069                                     Bacteria;Pseudomonadota;Gammaproteobacteria;Pseudomonadales;Pseudomonadaceae;Pseudomonas;Pseudomonas viridiflava;
...
```

to:

```
                    V        W      X       Y                                                          Z
1   1085_S4_kaiju.out 0.697392 418154   28901                                        Salmonella enterica
2   1085_S4_kaiju.out 0.692621 415293     562                                           Escherichia coli
3   1085_S4_kaiju.out 0.690187 413834     470                                    Acinetobacter baumannii
4   1085_S4_kaiju.out 0.625289 374921     573                                      Klebsiella pneumoniae
5   1085_S4_kaiju.out 0.285564 171223   33069                                    Pseudomonas viridiflava
...
```

Essentially taking the last column, splitting string based on ";", and returning second last value. Since some of the rows have values in column Z which are not of the same format as the rest, I want to remove those rows from the dataframe.

The following does the job, but takes FOREVER

```
library(stringr)

row_to_drop = c()
for(i in 1:nrow(tb)) {
  if (length(str_split(tb[i, 5], ";")[[1]]) < 8) {
    row_to_drop = c(row_to_drop, i)
  } else {
      tb[i, 5] = str_split(tb[i, 5], ";")[[1]][[7]]
  }
}
```

I have tried to look into vectorization but Im finding applying it to what Im trying to do here very confusing. Can I get some help on how to perform the changes to the dataframe I want much faster?

thanks

Comment: You say you want “second last value” but your example output uses the last value. Which do you want?

Comment: Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(head(df))`.

Comment: @zephryl it looks like the last value but since there is a ; at the end, the last element in the list produced by str_split is "" (empty string) so I want the sedond last one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `stringr::str_extract()`:

```r
library(stringr)

tb$Z <- str_extract(tb$Z, "[^;]*(?=;$)")
```

Result:

```r
                  V        W      X     Y                       Z
1 1085_S4_kaiju.out 0.697392 418154 28901     Salmonella enterica
2 1085_S4_kaiju.out 0.692621 415293   562        Escherichia coli
3 1085_S4_kaiju.out 0.690187 413834   470 Acinetobacter baumannii
4 1085_S4_kaiju.out 0.625289 374921   573   Klebsiella pneumoniae
5 1085_S4_kaiju.out 0.285564 171223 33069 Pseudomonas viridiflava
```

`"[^;]*"` matches sequential characters other than `";"`. `"(?=;$)"` matches characters immediately preceding the final `";"`. When combined, they match all text between the last two `";"`s.